# Post several Pictures on tumblr via api with Perl

Tags: perl, api, tumblr

I'm trying to post 3 pictures in tumblr via perl API ...

I have this code work good with one picture :

```
use LWP::Authen::OAuth;
use Data::Dumper;

my $ua = LWP::Authen::OAuth->new(
            oauth_consumer_key => 'xxx',
            oauth_consumer_secret => 'xxx',
            oauth_token => 'xxx',
            oauth_token_secret => 'xxx',
    );
my $url  = 'http://publicpics.free.fr/856833_10151249956981150_1285625380_o.jpg';
my %elements = (  
  'type' => 'photo', 
  'source' =>  $url,
);

print Dumper (\%elements);
print $ua->post( 'http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/xxxx.tumblr.com/post', [%elements] )->as_string;
```

I use this API Documentation http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posting

For several pictures you must past in parameters an Array ... So i Try this but dont' work :

```
use LWP::Authen::OAuth;
use Data::Dumper;

my $ua = LWP::Authen::OAuth->new(
            oauth_consumer_key => 'xxx',
            oauth_consumer_secret => 'xxx',
            oauth_token => 'xxx',
            oauth_token_secret => 'xxx',
    );
my @url  = ( 'http://publicpics.free.fr/856833_10151249956981150_1285625380_o.jpg' );
my %elements = (  
  'type' => 'photo', 
  'data' =>  \@url,
);

print Dumper (\%elements);
print $ua->post( 'http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/xxxx.tumblr.com/post', [%elements] )->as_string;
```

**I have this return :**

```
$VAR1 = {
      'data' => [
                  'http://publicpics.free.fr/856833_10151249956981150_1285625380_o.jpg'
                ],
      'type' => 'photo'
    };
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Connection: close
Date: Sun, 03 Mar 2013 22:01:13 GMT
Server: Apache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 92
Content-Type: application/json
Client-Date: Sun, 03 Mar 2013 22:01:13 GMT
Client-Peer: 66.6.36.55:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
P3P: CP="ALL ADM DEV PSAi COM OUR OTRo STP IND ONL"
X-Tumblr-Usec: D=112074

{"meta":{"status":400,"msg":"Bad Request"},"response":{"errors":["Error uploading photo."]}}
```

Comment: Thanks, but no change !

Answer (score 1):

Data is for local file, use source for internet accessible images

```
my %elements = (  
  'type' => 'photo', 
  'source' =>  \@url,
);
```

Regards,